# How can this be a characteristic function if it's not continuous

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions, density-function

Consider the following probability density function $f(x)$

\begin{cases} 
      0 & x<-1 \\
      1+x & z\in[-1,0] \\
      1-x & z\in[0,1] \\
      0 & x>1
\end{cases}
Then the characteristic function is calculated as
$$\varphi(t)=\mathbb{E(e^{itx})}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{itx}f(x)dx=\int_{-1}^0e^{itx}(1+x)dx+\int_0^1e^{itx}(1-x)dx$$
Which, according to Wolfram Alpha, yields
$$\varphi(t)=\frac{2-e^{it}-e^{-it}}{t^2}$$
How is this possible? The characteristic function is supposed to be uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ while this one obviously fails for $t=0$.

Comment: "This one" is obviously continuous at $0$, as an expansion of the numerator in powers of $t$ shows. Actually, for every $t$, $$\varphi(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2(-1)^n}{(2n+2)!}t^{2n},$$ hence $\varphi$ is even *analytic*.

Comment: @Did Well, I'm certainly confused now, how can it be seen that $\varphi$ is continuous, when at first sight $\varphi$ does not even seem to be defined in $t=0$?

Comment: The apparent singularity at $0$ is removable; it's a "hole" in the graph which can be filed in continuously. That's what the comment of @Did shows. Or, if you like, compute $\lim_{t \to 0} \phi(t)$ using l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Sorry @LeeMosher I edited my comment before seeing yours, however that makes me question something: Even if it is a removable discontinuity it would still be a discontinuity, and I thought the characteristic function was supposed to be continuous in all $\mathbb{R}$, even without such holes.

Comment: @F.Webber "A removable discontinuity would still be a discontinuity" precisely not. Look at the graph of $sin(x)/x$ and see if it is discontinuous. Also, the power series representation Did gave should convince you that this function is analytic on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As far as I know, functions with a removable discontinuity "can be made" continuous if we define a new function, piecewise, where we assign the function the value of the limit in that point, for instance, we assign $\varphi(0)=1$ in this case. This is a different function though, the previous function did not satisfy the definition of continuous function, only the new one does.

Comment: You should not be overly concerned with the fact that a dumb calculator (in this case Wolfram Alpha) does not immediately give you the correct function. Instead, you should understand that the analytic formula that you can derive from the dumb formula (as done in the first comment of @Did) gives the correct characteristic function. This happens *all the time* in analysis.

Comment: @LeeMosher That's surprising then, I was concerned because it's not just the result Wolfram yields, I used it merely for convenience, but doing the integrals manually also yields the same function, I don't understand how applying the definition does not yield a correct expression. I was particularly concerned because the value in $0$ is exactly something I required since it can be used to calculate the moments of the corresponding random variable, and of course I didn't know how to evaluate in $0$.

Comment: Doing the integral manually, as you call it, gives $\varphi(0)=1$ and yes, $\varphi(t)$ is very much defined at $t=0$. It is the function $\psi:t\mapsto(2-e^{it}-e^{-it})/t^2$ that has a singularity at $t=0$, not the function $\varphi$.

Comment: Finally, note that *every* characteristic function is continuous, simply because, if $t\to s$, then $e^{itX}\to e^{isX}$ pointwise hence, by Lebesgue DCT, $\varphi(t)\to\varphi(s)$.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly why I was concerned actually, because I thought my result was not a continuous function in $t=0$. I guess that, when doing the integral, I only got the general expression and at some point in the middle of the calculations I would have had to exclude the case $t=0$ and study it separately, which I didn't (referring to previous examples I computed manually).